# Connect two NICs from different linux servers together

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I'm running two linux servers with Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to connect them to act like this:

```
 +----------+      +----------+
 | Server 1 |      | Server 2 |
 +---eno1---+      +---eno2---+
      |                 |
      |                 |
      +--------+--------+
               |
               |
          ~-~--~--~-~-
            INTERNET
```

Basically, I want to use the internet speed of two or more servers and then combining it to connect to the public internet with the speed of all servers.
I would like to use the speed of every server on every server that is configured for my loadbalancing.
Let's say I got 1Gbp/s on server 1 and 1 Gbp/s on server 2, then i want to use the 2 Gbp/s on both these servers.

Maybe someone needs to know this, these two servers have been added to a [OVH vRack](https://www.ovh.com/world/solutions/vrack/), that acts like a network switch.

I don't know if this is really possible. I red about network bonding, but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Related from Ask Ubuntu: [How to merge multiple Internet connections into one?](https://askubuntu.com/q/53499/74792)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to connect multiple servers together. Not two network interfaces from one server.

Comment: Your diagram is lacking devices like switches and routers. You need to provide more details on how exactly those devices are connected for people to be able to help you.

Comment: If the two servers are sharing an Internet connection, there is nothing to combine.

Comment: I edited my question, maybe you are able to understand it a bit better now.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking for. Are you asking how to connect a third machine to the existing two machines where you have flexibility to modify the hardware of the existing machines? Are you asking how to get it so that each machine has access to the other's internet connection and so it has faster internet access when the other machine isn't heavily using its access. Or are you asking for a purely software solution over an existing private network? Or what?

Comment: "Are you asking how to get it so that each machine has access to the other's internet connection and so it has faster internet access when the other machine isn't heavily using its access." That is exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: Does the presence of the OVH vRack mean that in effect each computer has two network interfaces? If that's the case, then [Bonding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding) might be possible.

Comment: @harrymc No, every computer has one network interface.

Comment: Then I'm afraid this is not possible. A far-fetched idea would be to setup a VPN server on one computer, so connecting to it from the second computer will create a virtual network adapter that you could perhaps bond to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

[Bonding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding) of two network adapters
can achieve this configuration.

As you only have one network adapter, to create a second adapter that goes through
the second computer, a far-fetched idea would be to setup a VPN server on that computer.

In that case, connecting to the VPN server will create a virtual network adapter
that could perhaps be bonded to the physical one.

This solution is not simple to execute and much study will be required.
I cannot give detailed instructions for constructing it.